# How to convert String to Date getting only date and not time in Swift?

Tags: swift, date-formatting

I am currently getting a date from an API which is in format of:

> "2018-06-09T09:20:48"

I want to compare this date with today, tomorrow or else I have an another condition.

What I have done is this:

```
func dateFormatter(date: String){
     let today = Date() //2018-06-06 04:54:46 +0000

     let tomorrow = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: today) //2018-06-07 04:54:46 +0000

     let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

     dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

     let date_db = dateFormatter.date(from: date) //2018-06-06 12:32:02 +0000
     if today == date_db{
         print("It is today")
     }
     else if tomorrow = date_db {
         print("It is tomorrow")
     }
     else {
         "After Some Days"
     }
 }
```

This is not working as it is comparing the dateTime with dateTime, that is why, but I want only date from today, tomorrow and date_db so that I can compare them. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues. First, your date format is all wrong. You have the wrong timezone. You have the wrong locale. Once these are fixed you can parse the date string.

Then the proper way to determine if a date is today or tomorrow (ignoring time), is to use the `Calendar` methods `isDateInToday` and `isDateInTomorrow`.

Here's your code with everything fixed:

```
func dateFormatter(date: String){
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    // For a string like "2018-06-09T09:20:48"
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0) // assume date is GMT+0

    if let date_db = dateFormatter.date(from: date) {
        if Calendar.current.isDateInToday(date_db) {
            print("It is today")
        } else if Calendar.current.isDateInTomorrow(date_db) {
            print("It is tomorrow")
        } else {
            print("After Some Days")
        }
    } else {
        print("Unexpected date string")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, where can I learn about these things? Any source, you want to mention?

Comment: I wrote an article you may find helpful: http://www.maddysoft.com/articles/dates.html

Comment: Thanks a lot again.